# TikZ - Huffman tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, graphs

I used the [SimpleHuffman.lua](http://www.tug.org/texlive//devsrc/Master/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/graphdrawing/lua/pgf/gd/examples/SimpleHuffman.lua) file, placed it in the same folder as my `tex` file and compiled the following code ("35.8.3 How To Generate Nodes Inside an Algorithm" in pgfmanual) using `LuaTeX`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[lf]{MinionPro}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}

\pgfkeys{
/graph drawing/HuffmanLabel/.style={
/tikz/edge node={node[fill=gray!10,rectangle,font=\footnotesize,inner sep=1pt]{#1}}
},
/graph drawing/HuffmanNode/.style={
/tikz/.cd,circle,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,fill=black,minimum size=3pt
}
}

\usegdlibrary{SimpleHuffman}

\begin{document}
\tikz[scale=1,every node/.style={fill=yellow,circle,inner sep=1pt,minimum width=4mm},] \graph[simple Huffman layout, grow=left]{
"\textvisiblespace"  [probability=0.173684210526],
e [probability=0.1],
t [probability=0.0868421052632],
o [probability=0.0736842105263],
i [probability=0.0710526315789],
a [probability=0.0605263157895],
s [probability=0.0473684210526],
n [probability=0.0473684210526],
m [probability=0.0447368421053],
r [probability=0.0368421052632],
u [probability=0.0342105263158],
l [probability=0.0342105263158],
h [probability=0.0342105263158],
c [probability=0.0342105263158],
y [probability=0.0289473684211],
f [probability=0.0289473684211],
g [probability=0.0263157894737],
p [probability=0.0210526315789],
w [probability=0.0157894736842],
"." [probability=0.0131578947368],
d [probability=0.0105263157895],
b [probability=0.0105263157895],
x [probability=0.00526315789474],
"," [probability=0.00263157894737],
v [probability=0.00263157894737],
k [probability=0.00263157894737],
};
\end{document}
```

The problem I get is that the part marked in the following image has three child nodes instead of two, also the label is misplaced:

[image: SimpleHuffman TikZ]

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

*Edit:* 
Here is a minimal example, showing the problem. Thanks to Andrew Swann

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[lf]{MinionPro}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}

\pgfkeys{
/graph drawing/HuffmanLabel/.style={
/tikz/edge node={node[fill=gray!10,rectangle,font=\footnotesize,inner sep=1pt]{#1}}
},
/graph drawing/HuffmanNode/.style={
/tikz/.cd,circle,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,fill=black,minimum size=3pt
}
}

\usegdlibrary{SimpleHuffman}

\begin{document}
\tikz[scale=1,every node/.style={fill=yellow,circle,inner sep=1pt,minimum width=4mm}]
\graph[simple Huffman layout, grow=left]{
A [probability=0.4], B [probability=0.4], C [probability=0.2]
};
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well the manual does say that the library is not intended to be used in layout graphs! Also, is TeX dealing with the probabilities or Lua? Because they seem too fine-grained for the former.

Comment: @cfr Thanks I think I can avoid the crossed edges by slightly changing equal probabilities to force an order. I'm pretty sure only Lua uses the probabilities and on the first view it seemed to me that the tree is correct but the marked part obviously isn't.

Comment: What exactly is it doing? What is a Huffman tree, Simple or not?

Comment: The algorithm placed in the Lua file builds a huffman tree based on the nodes supplied in the tex document. I was wondering if someone knows how to fix the part marked in the image. I don't want a solution fixing the crossed edge problem, I just wanted to have a Simple Huffman graph like the one in pgfmanual, but my has the problem at marked part.

Comment: A minimal example demonstrating the placement problem consists of the three nodes  `A [probability=0.4],
B [probability=0.4],
C [probability=0.2],`

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thanks that's a very good minimal example showing the problem. I'll edit my code.

Comment: It seems the algorithm works correct if number of Nodes is even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two approaches.  The first does not solve your particular case, but can help in a number of situations.  The second shows how to change the overall style of the drawing to avoid overlap.

You can adjust the placement of a final node by adding a `nudge` argument, e.g.

```
B [probability=0.4,nudge up=2mm],
```

will place the node `B` a little higher than the algorithm would otherwise use.  This can be enough to uncover an accidental overlap.  In the minimal example I provided this gives

[image: Sample output]

when combined with adding the `above` option to the `edge node`s.  Without `above` you would have to move this node further to reduce the overlap.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}

\pgfkeys{
/graph drawing/HuffmanLabel/.style={
/tikz/edge node={node[fill=gray!10,rectangle,font=\footnotesize,inner
sep=1pt,above]{#1}}
},
/graph drawing/HuffmanNode/.style={
/tikz/.cd,circle,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,fill=black,minimum size=3pt
}
}

\usegdlibrary{SimpleHuffman}

\begin{document}
\tikz[scale=1,every node/.style={fill=yellow,circle,inner
sep=1pt,minimum width=4mm}] \graph[simple Huffman
layout,grow=left]{
A [probability=0.4],
B [probability=0.4,nudge up=2mm],
C [probability=0.2],
};
\end{document}
```

See section 27.6 Fine-Tuning Positions of Nodes of the [`pgfmanual`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=en) for other similar options.

Unfortunately for your example you need to adjust the vertical position of a node that is not part of the input and so can't directly apply such a `nudge` option.

As an alternative work around, you can move the labels of the edges by using a `pos` argument in the `HuffmanLabel/.style` and use decorations to make the edges curved rather than straight:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,decorations,decorations.pathmorphing}

\pgfkeys{
/graph drawing/HuffmanLabel/.style={/tikz/edge node={
node[fill=gray!10,rectangle,font=\footnotesize,inner sep=1pt,pos=0.7]{#1}}},
/graph drawing/HuffmanNode/.style={
/tikz/.cd,circle,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,fill=black,minimum size=3pt}}

\usegdlibrary{SimpleHuffman}

\begin{document}
\tikz[scale=1,
  every node/.style={fill=yellow,circle,inner sep=1pt,minimum width=4mm},
  every edge/.append style={decorate,decoration={bent,amplitude=3mm}}]
  \graph[simple Huffman layout, grow=left]{
"\textvisiblespace"  [probability=0.173684210526],
e [probability=0.1],
t [probability=0.0868421052632],
o [probability=0.0736842105263],
i [probability=0.0710526315789],
a [probability=0.0605263157895],
s [probability=0.0473684210526],
n [probability=0.0473684210526],
m [probability=0.0447368421053],
r [probability=0.0368421052632],
u [probability=0.0342105263158],
l [probability=0.0342105263158],
h [probability=0.0342105263158],
c [probability=0.0342105263158],
y [probability=0.0289473684211],
f [probability=0.0289473684211],
g [probability=0.0263157894737],
p [probability=0.0210526315789],
w [probability=0.0157894736842],
"." [probability=0.0131578947368],
d [probability=0.0105263157895],
b [probability=0.0105263157895],
x [probability=0.00526315789474],
"," [probability=0.00263157894737],
v [probability=0.00263157894737],
k [probability=0.00263157894737],
};

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! So the `SimpleHuffman.lua` is correct and in this case only the edges were overlapped completely which for me looked like a node with three children.